# logging utf-8 chars in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, logging, unicode, utf-8

I'd like to log (or even print) some messages that are utf-8 encoded unicode ; having run into this a lot I collected a bunch of fixes none of which actually seems to work in my case (python3 in a jupyter notebook). What i have so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/local/bin/python3
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stderr)
!export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

then i try any of

```
logging.info(u'שלום')
logging.info(unicode('שלום','utf-8'))
logging.info(u'שלום'.encode('utf-8'))
```

all of which hit the dreaded

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

At this point i am willing to sacrifice a goat to the unicode monkey-god if that would help, can anyone weigh in  (e.g. what kind of goat?)

Comment: If you are using Python 3, then there is no need to use `u'...'` notation for (Unicode) strings. And there is no built-in type `unicode`, so you should see a NameError. And for re-encoding STDOUT, you have to wrap the writer around `sys.stdout.buffer`. To me, this code looks like you are using Python 2, actually.

Comment: my jupyter was reporting python3 , incorrectly.  I replaced sys.stdout with sys.stdout.buffer and hit an error. ( `'OutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer')  `But restarting the kernel allowed the first two logging.info calls to perform.

Comment: If you aren't using Python 3, you should adjust the title and the tags, so people trying to help can do so more efficiently.